# Declaring an Array in Java with a Generic Type

Tags: java, arrays

Please consider the following code:

```
public class A<T> {  
    public void main(String[] args) {
        A<String>[] array = new A<String>[10];
        System.out.println(array.length);
    }
}
```

I am trying to define (and allocate space for it) an array of 10 elements
where each element of the array is of type A. I thought the above code would do it, but it fails to compile.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: [Take a look how `ArrayList` does it](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java) . Baseline: generics and arrays do not mix well

Comment: you can't create an array of a class with generic type. You could do it with raw types, but that is something you should avoid.

Comment: Type Erasure makes it so that you can't do this. Simply define your array as `A[]`.